# Why is rows(callback) function from db.all returning undefined while rows is defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I'm calling a function to see if an email adress is in the db. It's either an empty or filled array. Whenever i return this value it is undefined afterwards. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance!

I have tried using next() and promises.

The function that calls the db query function.

```
    const emailExists = async function(req,res,next){
        let emailInDb = await usermodel.getOneByEmail(req, next);
        console.log(emailInDb);
       if(emailInDb.length !==0){
        res.send('email already in use!');
       }
       else{
         return next();
        }
    };
```

The db query.

```
    const getOneByEmail = function (req, next){
        let db = new sqlite3.Database(dbPath, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            }
        console.log('Connected to books db.');
         });

        db.all(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?`, [req.body.email], 
        (err, rows) => {
             console.log(rows);
             return rows;
         });
     };
```

console.log(emailInDb) gives undefined.
While console.log(rows) gives an array with results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting `await` in front of a non async function does not magically make the function wait for the db-calls to resolve. You need to wrap the db-calls in a promise, e.g:

```
 const getOneByEmail = (req, next) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let db = new sqlite3.Database(dbPath, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
                reject(err);
            }
            console.log('Connected to books db.');           
        });
        db.all(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?`, [req.body.email],
            (err, rows) => {
                // TODO: check for error here and reject
                console.log(rows);
                resolve(rows);
            });
    });
};
```

Note that you shouldn't connect to the database each time you call getOneByEmail, instead reuse the connection...